# Gitlab CI using Docker - how to rename the build container?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We have set up our CI environment using Gitlab CI using Docker images as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html). 
Using the default settings the build containers get rather generic names like `runner-oh2M8zk--project-206-concurrent-0-build-4`.

The machine, that hosts the Gitlab runner, also runs several other containers. To be able to monitor activity on that machine, we want to be able to identify which projects (and maybe commits or branches) triggered a certain build container. With the current naming this is next to impossible.

Afaik, the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html) does not give any hint on how to specify the name for a container run by Gitlab runner. Is there any option (presumably in `.gitlab-ci.yml`) to set that name or at least specify a prefix/suffix for it?